# How do I upgrade from drupal 9 to 10 when dynamic entity reference 3.0 and up require drupal 10 first?

Tags: 9

I am trying to upgrade my drupal 9 site to drupal 10. I installed the Upgrade Status module and it's only complaints are I need to upgrade linkchecker and dynamic entity reference. The problem is that to upgrade linkchecker to 2.0 I need to upgrade dynamic entity reference to at least 3.0, but dynamic entity reference 3.0 and up all require drupal 10.

How do I upgrade those two so that I can upgrade drupal 9 to drupal 10 if dynamic entity reference requires drupal 10? It seems like a loop to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That situation is [documented on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/how-to-upgrade-from-drupal-9-to-drupal-10#s-resolve-modules-that-are-only-compatible-with-drupal-10).

Comment: Ooh I will try that, thanks!

Why did you get downvoted?

Comment:  Probably it is because I did not copy and paste the documentation to this site.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks @cilefen!!